# Checkout system giving strange result

Tags: ruby

So I'm making a checkout system similar to [this](http://codekata.com/kata/kata09-back-to-the-checkout/). However, I have 3 items (A, B and C priced at $3.11, $5.00 and $11.23, respectively).

The conditions are such that item A has a buy-one-get-one-free offer and item B reduces to $4.50 if 3 or more units are bought. The problem comes when testing the code.

I've written the following code to solve the exercise:

```
class PriceDiscount  # Applies price discounts for a specific number of items

# Initial method with item price and item quantity parameters
  def initialize(itemprice, quantity)
    @itemprice = itemprice
    @quantity = quantity
  end

# "calculate_for" method which calculates the discount for the specific number of items
  def calculate_for(quantity)
    (quantity / @quantity).floor * @itemprice
  end

end


class PricePolicy  # Calculates the price for a certain quantity of items after discounts

# Initial method with the original price and discounts as the paremeters
  def initialize(orgprice, *discounts)
    @orgprice = orgprice
    @discounts = discounts
  end

# Calculates the discounted price of a number of items
  def price_for(quantity)
    quantity * @orgprice - discount_for(quantity)
  end

# Calculates the discount which is given for a number of items
  def discount_for(quantity)
    @discounts.inject(0) do |mem, discount|
      mem + discount.calculate_for(quantity)
    end
  end
end


# Rule list set up for great flexibility as each rule is specified in one line
RULES = {
  'A' => PricePolicy.new(3.11, PriceDiscount.new(3.11, 2)), 
  'B' => PricePolicy.new(5.00, PriceDiscount.new(4.50, 2)),
  'C' => PricePolicy.new(11.23),
}


class Checkout # Checkout class which applies the rules to each item that is scanned

# Initial method which has the rules and items as its parameters
  def initialize(rules)
    @rules = rules
    @items = Hash.new
  end

# Method to set up the array in which scanned items are stored
  def scan(item)
    @items[item] ||= 0
    @items[item] += 1
  end

# Method which totals the price of the scanned items
  def total
    @items.inject(0) do |mem, (item, quantity)|
      mem + price_for(item, quantity)
    end
  end

  private 
  def price_for(item, quantity)
    if rule_for(item)
      rule_for(item).price_for(quantity)
    else
      raise "Invalid item '#{item}'"
    end
  end

  def rule_for(item)
    @rules[item]
  end
end
```

And this is the tester:

```
require 'test/unit'
require_relative './CheckoutSystem.rb'

class TestPrice < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def price(goods)
    co = Checkout.new(RULES)
    goods.split(//).each { |item| co.scan(item) }
    co.total
  end


  def test_totals

    # Scenario 1 with basket: A, B, A, A, C
    assert_equal(22.45, price("ABAAC").round(2))

    # Scenario 2 with basket: A, A
    assert_equal(3.11, price("AA").round(2))

    # Scenario 3 with basket: B, B, A, B
    assert_equal(16.61, price("BBAB").round(2))
  end

end
```

Scenario 1 and 2 give the correct values. However, scenario 3 gives the value of $13.11 when it should in fact be $16.61.

Does anyone have any idea where I've made a mistake? I've been going over it for ages and can't fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change your program to pass the test cases, you have to change:

```
'B' => PricePolicy.new(5.00, PriceDiscount.new(4.50, 2)),
```

To

```
'B' => PricePolicy.new(5.00, PriceDiscount.new(1.50, 3)),
```

This way, when the user purchases 3 'B' items, they will receive a discount of 1.5, meaning that the total price of the 3 items will change from 15 to 13.5 (4.50 each.)

Note that in this case, if the user buys 4 'B' items, they will receive a discount on the first 3, but NO discount on the fourth item.

---

To solve the problem to work properly when '3 or more items' are purchased, the discount.calculate_for method will have to be changed. This is because 'A' and 'B' items will calculate their discounts differently:

A straightforward implementation would be to define a 'type' for each of the situations. In the example below, an empty type simply represents the 'x or more items' situation, and a bogo type represents a 'buy x and get a flat discount' situation.

```
class PriceDiscount
  def initialize(itemprice, quantity, type = nil)
    @itemprice = itemprice
    @quantity = quantity
    @type = type
    raise "Invalid type '#{type}'" if @type != 'bogo' && @type != nil
  end

  def calculate_for(quantity)
    if (@type == 'bogo')
      (quantity / @quantity) * @itemprice
    elsif quantity >= @quantity
      (quantity.to_f / @quantity) * @itemprice
    else
      0
    end
  end
end
```

And the rules would be updated as follows:

```
RULES = {
  'A' => PricePolicy.new(3.11, PriceDiscount.new(3.11, 2, 'bogo')), 
  'B' => PricePolicy.new(5.00, PriceDiscount.new(1.50, 3)),
  'C' => PricePolicy.new(11.23),
}
```

The bogo items would use the same calculation as you had before, meaning that AA has 1 discount, AAA has 1 discount, and AAAA has 2 discounts.
The 'x or more items' will first check if the number of items meets the threshold, and if so, it will apply the discounted rate to every single one of those items. (In this case, BBB will apply the specified discount of 1.50. BBBB will apply a modified version of the discount --> 2.00, to match the 4 items.)

As well, you can drop the '.floor' method for ints --> it will automatically floor when converting. To get non-integer results, you can see that I've converted one of the values in the second calculation to a float.

Try running these changes with these change-specific tests:

```
assert_equal(13.11, price("BBA").round(2))
assert_equal(21.11, price("BBBBA").round(2))
assert_equal(22.45, price("AAAABC").round(2))
assert_equal(25.56, price("AAAAABC").round(2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I'll try to implement the fixed code like you described now.